# Group two non-adjacent columns into 2d array for Excel VBA Script

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I think this question might be related to [Ms Excel -> 2 columns into a 2 dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796852/ms-excel-2-columns-into-a-2-dimensional-array) but I can't quite make the connection.

I have a VBA script for filling missing missing data.  I select two adjacent columns, and it finds any gaps in the second column and linearly interpolates based on (possibly irregular) spacing in the first column.  For instance, I could use it on this data:

```
1    7
2    14
3    21
5    35
5.1    
6    42
7
8     
9    45
```

to get this output

```
1    7
2    14
3    21
5    35
5.1  35.7  <---1/10th the way between 35&42
6    42
7    43   <-- 1/3 the way between 42 & 45
8    44   <-- 2/3 the way between 42 & 45 
9    45
```

This is very useful for me.

My trouble is that it only works on contiguous columns.  I would like to be able to select two columns that are not adjacent to each other and have it work the same way. My code starts out like this:

```
Dim addr As String
addr = Selection.Address

Dim nR As Long
Dim nC As Long

'Reads Selected Cells' Row and Column Information
nR = Range(addr).Rows.Count   
nC = Range(addr).Columns.Count
```

When I run this with contiguous columns selected, `addr` shows up in the Locals window with a value like `"$A$2:$B$8"` and `nC` = 2

When I run this with *non*-contiguous columns selected, `addr` shows up in the Locals window with a value like `"$A$2:$A$8,$C$2:$C$8"` and `nC` = 1.

Later on in the script, I collect the values in each column into an array.  Here's how I deal with the second column, for example:

```
 'Creates a Column 2 (col1) array, determines cells needed to interpolate for, changes font to bold and red, and reads its values
        Dim col2() As Double
        ReDim col2(0 To nR + 1)
        i = 1
        Do Until i > nR
            If IsEmpty(Selection(i, 2)) Or Selection(i, 2) = 0 Or Selection(i, 2) = -901 Then
                Selection(i, 2).Font.Bold = True
                Selection(i, 2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 69, 0)
                col2(i) = 9999999
            Else
                col2(i) = Selection(i, 2)
            End If

            i = i + 1
            Loop
```

This is also busted, because even if my selection is `"$A$2:$A$8,$C$2:$C$8"` VBA will treat `Selection(1,2)` as a reference to `$B$2`, not the desired `$C$2`.

Anyone have a suggestion for how I can get VBA to treat non-contiguous selection the way it treats contiguous?

Comment: why not simply select the whole range and then let the sub act for the first and last column instead of dealing with non-contiguous ranges?

Comment: @DirkReichel Interesting idea.  I could do that.  It would take a bit of rewriting, but at least I can see exactly how that would work.  Still would like to know how to do it with disjoint ranges, though.

Comment: another question... assuming the values you provided are in A1:B8 then you simply doing the same like (starting in C2) `=IF(B2="",(A2-A1)/(A3-A1)*(B3-B1)+B1,B2)`, am I correct?

Comment: Not quite - I hadn't shown this, but the script works if I am missing multiple values in column B.  I edited the question to show that better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dealing with "disjoint ranges."  Use the `Areas` collection, e.g., as described [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/620713-disjoint-range.html#post3077768).  The first column should be in `Selection.Areas(1)` and the second column should be in `Selection.Areas(2)`.

Comment: If I add `secondCol = Selection.Areas(2)` it looks like it is successfully reading the values from the second column, but I can't act on them as locations.  (For instance, the fifth cell of ht esecond column in my example is blank, so when `i=5` the test  `IsEmpty(secondCol(i, 1))` correctly returns true, but `secondCol(i, 1).Font.Bold = True` gives a _424: object required_ error.

Comment: Just at a brief glance, first you might try setting a watch for secondCol (right click and "Add Watch"), then you can step through your program and see whether it correctly sets an object reference. Also is secondCol a 1D or 2D array?

Comment: With selection = "$A$2:$A$8,$C$2:$C$8", `secondCol = Selection.Areas(2)` is a 1-D array that doesn't appear to "remember"" where the cells it came from are.

Comment: @Adam `secondCol = Selection.Areas(2)` will only hold the values... you need `Set secondCol = Selection.Areas(2)`!

Comment: Yes!  Thank you cxw & @DirkReichel